# Android - How can I Attach a WebView to an Activity after creating it with the Application Context

Tags: android, webview, mutable-context-wrapper

I am creating an Android WebView in the background using the Application Context so that it is loaded and ready when I need to display it. I attach it to my Activity using addView when it is needed. This mostly works great, however when I try to open an HTML select dropdown I get a crash:

> ```
> android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:540)
>   at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:259)
>   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
>   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
>   at com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.input.SelectPopupDialog.show(SelectPopupDialog.java:217)
>   at com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.ContentViewCore.showSelectPopup(ContentViewCore.java:2413)
>   at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
>   at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:27)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
> ```

I'm assuming this is because I created the WebView with the ApplicationContext. My question is: is there any way to work around this issue? Is there any way to "attach" the existing WebView to a different Activity or Window so that the Dialog can be created? Is there any way to "hack" this together using Reflection by changing the Context at runtime?

EDIT: As suggested below I tested using a [MutableContextWrapper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/MutableContextWrapper.html) and it appears to solve this problem nicely!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, we've actually run into the same issue (using a `WebView` in a retained `Fragment` to prevent page reloads, while not leaking an `Activity` context) and the short answer seems to be that there's no really clean way to do so. I've even tried a custom `WebView` subclass that returned the host `Activity`'s window token instead of the `WebView`'s own token, to no success.

We ended up using reflection, as you suggested, to modify the underlying context:

```
public static boolean setContext(View v, Context ctx) {
    try {
        final Field contextField = View.class.getDeclaredField("mContext");
        contextField.setAccessible(true);
        contextField.set(v, ctx);
        return (v.getContext() == ctx);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException | NoSuchFieldException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, String.valueOf(e), e);
        return false;
    }
}
```

which just sets the `mContext` field on the `View` instance and returns true if it was successfully modified. However, I saw another suggestion recently (and **I haven't tested this**, so YMMV) to use `MutableContextWrapper`. So you would inflate the `WebView` with the `Activity` `Context`, wrapped in a `MutableContextWrapper`. Then, when you need to release the previous reference, you'd cast that `WebView`'s `Context` to a `MutableContextWrapper`, and then set the base `Context` to the new `Activity`. So something like this to inflate the layout:

```
MutableContextWrapper contextWrapper = new MutableContextWrapper(activity);

WebView webView = (WebView) LayoutInflater.from(contextWrapper)
        .inflate(R.layout.your_webview_layout, theParent, false);
```

Then, to re-attach to a new `Activity`:

```
if (webView.getContext() instanceof MutableContextWrapper) {
    ((MutableContextWrapper) webView.getContext()).setBaseContext(newActivity);
}
```

Comment: I had tested a solution using reflection after writing this question and it seemed to work (although I had to go a few levels deeper for Android 4.4 with the Chromium WebView). Thanks for pointing out MutableContextWrapper, I was not aware of that class and it looks like it could do the trick! I'll try that out and report back.

Comment: MutableContextWrapper appears to solve this nicely, I'll update the question with that fact, thanks again!